# WordPress auto-update caused image display issues (403 error) after upgrading to version 6.2.2

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website hosted on SiteGround, and recently my site was automatically updated to the latest WordPress version (6.2.2). Since the update, most of my site's images are no longer displayed, specifically those larger than 200x200 pixels. When attempting to load these images, I noticed network requests similar to the following:

```
https://www.****.com/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://www.****.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/LOGO1-e1433751754120.png&nocache=1
```

Unfortunately, all of these requests result in a 403 error. It's worth mentioning that my site is also behind Cloudflare.

Has anyone else experienced this issue after updating to WordPress version 6.2.2? I'm curious to know what could be causing this problem and how I can resolve it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

p.s.
In addition to this issue, I have one more wired one, almost all my visitors start getting the `Our system thinks you might be a robot` page and request for CAPTCHA, why is this happening and can I solve it? (most of my user are not technical so this page drive them away)